# To show that this IVP does/does not have a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the IVP $y'=2√y, y(0)=0$. I find $y=x^2$ as the only solution to the problem. But I am asked to show that it does *not* have a unique solution. Is there a mistake or am I just wrong? Is there a sufficient condition for the existence of more than one solution to an IVP?

Comment: did you check to make sure you didnt divide by zero when you separated variables?

Comment: Oh. There's the trivial solution isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard type of example problem to illustrate the difference of the Cauchy-Peano and Picard-Lindelöf theorems. You get any of
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x<c,\\(x-c)^2,&x\ge c,\end{cases}
$$
as valid solutions to this IVP.

Comment: I understand now that the trivial solution is also a solution. But could you elaborate on the first line of your answer please?

Comment: probably worth showing how you actually come up with this family

Comment: I meant the part about Cauchy-Peano and Picard-Lindelof existence theorems.

Comment: @HritRoy the idea is that the Lipschitz condition is what gives you uniqueness, here you have continuity alone, this gives you the existence of the family

Answer (score 1):

When you separate variables, recall that either $y=0$, which is easy to see is a solution, or 
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{\sqrt{y}}=2\int \mathrm dt\implies \sqrt{y}=t+c\\
\implies y=t^2+2ct+c
$$
and $c=0$ thanks to BC, you have, as you found
$$
y=t^2
$$

Comment: sigh, why the downvote

Comment: I felt this answer was inadequate, as it does not address solutions other than the trivial one.

Comment: I acknowledge your answer is still correct, but it was too late to undo the vote

Comment: @Dylan How could this be inadequate? The question is "to show that this IVP does/does not have a unique solution." Unique means one.

Comment: @Dylan regardless, I appreciate you taking the time to explain

Comment: If it's any consolation, I upvoted :)

Comment: I guess it's a case of "it's correct, but I want more". In my mind, the trivial solution is, well, trivial, and uninteresting. You'd make a much stronger case by pointing to the non-trivial family of solutions. Although, I do concede that it was wrong to expect something the question doesn't ask, so I removed my vote.

Comment: That may well be, but in this case the trivial solution was forgotten when separating variables without considering it (and it is important to remember to insure you aren't dividing by zero when you separate variables). Also, when looking for counterexamples, trivial ones should not be overlooked! I find they help me surprisingly often